# Unable to use createddate in picklist field default value formula editor

Tags: formula, picklist, createddate

I am trying to populate a default value in a picklist field by using below formula:

```
IF((DATEVALUE(Createddate) - Manufactured_Date__c)<365,"Yes","No")
```

I am getting an error saying

> `CreatedDate` cannot be used in this type of formula

Why do I get this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: You cannot use the record fields in the default value, since it has not been created yet. You can look at setting this field in a record-triggered flow after creation.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail.  Where are building this formula?  Formula fields cannot populate a picklist field, please [edit] to clarify what you are trying to do.